# Write Xpath to select field based on upper field

Tags: jquery, html, xpath

I am not xpath expert and tried many solution from internet but still unable to select particular field.

**Html :**

```
<div class="WJYM">
    <ul class="WEXM WMXM" role="list">
        <li class="WKWM WAYM" role="listitem" data-automation-id="formLabelRequired">
            <div class="WMWM WCWM">
                <label id="56$383927--uid80-formLabel" data-automation-id="formLabel">Category</label>
                <div class="WNWM wd-036e7e5d-ab15-4210-a313-bcfdb6b9bac2" aria-hidden="true">Category</div>
            </div>
            <div class="WOWM">
                <div class="WOXH">
                    <div class="WKPV WAPV WHOV WJ3 WJUV WPOV WNQV" data-automation-id="responsiveMonikerInput" id="56$383927--uid80" tabindex="-2">
                        <div class="WMWP WLVP WAWP" style="opacity: 0;" data-automation-hiddensearch="false">
                            <input type="text" class="gwt-TextBox WKWP" autocomplete="off" placeholder="search" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false" aria-labelledby="56$383927--uid80-formLabel" aria-required="true"><span class="WMVP"><div role="presentation" data-automation-id="icon" class="WEHJ WDHJ WNVP"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" role="presentation" focusable="false" class="wd-icon-x wd-icon" height="24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g class="wd-icon-container" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g>
            <path class="wd-icon-fill" d="M5.996 4.582a.5.5 0 0 0-.717-.003l-.7.7a.504.504 0 0 0 .003.717L10.586 12l-6.004 6.004a.5.5 0 0 0-.003.717l.7.7c.197.197.514.2.717-.003L12 13.414l6.004 6.004a.5.5 0 0 0 .717.003l.7-.7a.504.504 0 0 0-.003-.717L13.414 12l6.004-6.004a.5.5 0 0 0 .003-.717l-.7-.7a.504.504 0 0 0-.717.003L12 10.586 5.996 4.582z"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
</div><div role="presentation" data-automation-id="icon" class="WEHJ WDHJ WHWP"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" role="presentation" focusable="false" class="wd-icon-prompts wd-icon" height="24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g class="wd-icon-container" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g>
            <path class="wd-icon-fill" d="M4 6.505C4 6.226 4.214 6 4.505 6h.99c.279 0 .505.214.505.505v.99A.497.497 0 0 1 5.495 8h-.99A.497.497 0 0 1 4 7.495v-.99zm0 5c0-.279.214-.505.505-.505h.99c.279 0 .505.214.505.505v.99a.497.497 0 0 1-.505.505h-.99A.497.497 0 0 1 4 12.495v-.99zm0 5c0-.279.214-.505.505-.505h.99c.279 0 .505.214.505.505v.99a.497.497 0 0 1-.505.505h-.99A.497.497 0 0 1 4 17.495v-.99zm4-10C8 6.226 8.229 6 8.5 6h11c.276 0 .5.214.5.505v.99a.506.506 0 0 1-.5.505h-11a.495.495 0 0 1-.5-.505v-.99zm0 5c0-.279.229-.505.5-.505h11c.276 0 .5.214.5.505v.99a.506.506 0 0 1-.5.505h-11a.495.495 0 0 1-.5-.505v-.99zm0 5c0-.279.229-.505.5-.505h11c.276 0 .5.214.5.505v.99a.506.506 0 0 1-.5.505h-11a.495.495 0 0 1-.5-.505v-.99z"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
</div></span>
                            <div role="presentation" data-automation-id="icon" class="WEHJ WDHJ WLWP">
                                <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" role="presentation" focusable="false" class="wd-icon-search wd-icon" height="24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                    <g class="wd-icon-container" fill-rule="evenodd">
                                        <g fill-rule="nonzero">
                                            <path class="wd-icon-background" d="M16.896 14.775l3.643 3.642a.995.995 0 0 1-.004 1.418l-.7.7c-.39.39-1.032.39-1.418.004l-3.642-3.643a7 7 0 1 1 2.121-2.121zM11 16a5 5 0 1 0 0-10 5 5 0 0 0 0 10z" />
                                            <path class="wd-icon-fill" d="M17.32 15.906l2.859 2.858a.5.5 0 0 1 .003.717l-.7.7a.5.5 0 0 1-.718-.002l-2.858-2.86a8 8 0 1 1 1.414-1.414zM11 17a6 6 0 1 0 0-12 6 6 0 0 0 0 12z" />
                                        </g>
                                    </g>
                                </svg>
                            </div><span class="WOWP"></span></div>
                        <div class="gwt-Label WKQV">search input</div>
                        <div class="WPPV">
                            <ul tabindex="-2" class="WIBP WOPV WNBP" role="listbox" data-automation-id="selectedItemList"></ul>
                        </div><span class="WHQV" aria-hidden="true" data-automation-id="promptIcon" tabindex="-2" aria-invalid="false"><div data-automation-id="icon" class="WEHJ WDHJ WIQV"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" role="presentation" focusable="false" class="wd-icon-prompts wd-icon" height="24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g class="wd-icon-container" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g>
            <path class="wd-icon-fill" d="M4 6.505C4 6.226 4.214 6 4.505 6h.99c.279 0 .505.214.505.505v.99A.497.497 0 0 1 5.495 8h-.99A.497.497 0 0 1 4 7.495v-.99zm0 5c0-.279.214-.505.505-.505h.99c.279 0 .505.214.505.505v.99a.497.497 0 0 1-.505.505h-.99A.497.497 0 0 1 4 12.495v-.99zm0 5c0-.279.214-.505.505-.505h.99c.279 0 .505.214.505.505v.99a.497.497 0 0 1-.505.505h-.99A.497.497 0 0 1 4 17.495v-.99zm4-10C8 6.226 8.229 6 8.5 6h11c.276 0 .5.214.5.505v.99a.506.506 0 0 1-.5.505h-11a.495.495 0 0 1-.5-.505v-.99zm0 5c0-.279.229-.505.5-.505h11c.276 0 .5.214.5.505v.99a.506.506 0 0 1-.5.505h-11a.495.495 0 0 1-.5-.505v-.99zm0 5c0-.279.229-.505.5-.505h11c.276 0 .5.214.5.505v.99a.506.506 0 0 1-.5.505h-11a.495.495 0 0 1-.5-.505v-.99z"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
</div></span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="WKWM" role="listitem">
            <div class="WMWM WCWM">
                <label id="56$383068--uid81-formLabel" data-automation-id="formLabel" for="56$383068--uid81-input">Comment</label>
                <div class="WNWM wd-036e7e5d-ab15-4210-a313-bcfdb6b9bac2" aria-hidden="true">Comment</div>
            </div>
            <div class="WOWM">
                <div class="WOXH WPXH">
                    <div class="WIMY textArea WBMY WJ3" data-automation-id="textArea" id="56$383068--uid81">
                        <textarea class="gwt-TextArea WMMY WANY WBNY" data-automation-id="textAreaField" role="textbox" aria-label="Process Comment" id="56$383068--uid81-input" aria-invalid="false" tabindex="0"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Screenshot about how field display in webpage :
[image]

I want to select `Comment` based on it's upper box called `Category`.

I have separate xpath of both :

**Category :**

```
//label[text()='Category']/../following-sibling::div//span[contains(@data-automation-id,'promptIcon')]
```

**Comment :** `//label[text()='Comment']`

I can not use alone xpath of `Comment` to select it as webpage has some other comment fields and I am getting multiple values.

So I want to select only that `comment field` which is following `Category dropdown`.

I tried some tricks with `following-sibling` with both fields but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to check what is the common thing about both elements, and they are both `li` with `label` tags inside them, this xpath should do the work:

```
//li[.//label[text()="Category"]]/following-sibling::li//label[text()="Comment"]
```

Comment: Awesome help. Thanks :)